# Getting correct data order from queryset python

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a problem, then when I'm trying to get specific values from query set its giving me it in alphabet order.
Example:

```
account_data = Account.objects.all()
[<Account: Merchant: ID: 267 (google@gmail.com), Currency: RUB, Brand: Brand NEWW (google@gmail.com)>,
 <Account: Merchant: ID: 265 (goole@gmail.com), Currency: EUR, Brand: Brand new (google@gmail.com)>,
 <Account: Merchant: ID: 264 (google@gmail.com), Currency: USD, Brand: Brand new2 (google@gmail.com)>,
 <Account: Merchant: ID: 266 (google@gmail.com), Currency: TRY, Brand: Brand new 3 (google@gmail.com)>,
 <Account: Merchant: ID: 269 (google@gmail.com), Currency: BGN, Brand: Brand new 4 (google@gmail.com)>]

currency = ', '.join(sorted(list(account_data.values_list('currency__code', flat=True))))
Out[66]: 'BGN, EUR, RUB, TRY, USD'
```

And this issue appears for all values, need to get currency connected to a specific account, not random or alphabet order.

Desired result: RUB, EUR, USD, TRY, BGN

Comment: can you write your desired result in the question as well?

Comment: Done, check please

Comment: You are using sorted function, I think that is the problem

Comment: if you want in original order then don't use `sorted()`

Comment: if I remove sorted, its giving me incorrect order again, different from with it, but also incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use oder_by("pk")
then you get the orders in the order of creation